# WPF: Remove dotted border around focused item in styled listbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, focus, border

I have a horizontal listbox with a custom controlIemplate. The selected item gets a dotted frame when focused. Anyone know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You need to set FocusVisualStyle of each ListBoxItem to null. Steps are bellow

1) Create ItemContainerStyle for the ListBox

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"> 
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/> ....
```

2) Set that style to Listbox

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"
```

Comment: This answer works great, but huge heads up here: If you use this method, your controls **will not display any indicator of which is focused in Windows 8!** With the `FocusVisualStyle` disabled in Windows 7, controls like Buttons still retains a blue overall highlight, but in Windows 8 it's completely impossible to tell which control in a group is focused.

Comment: Good to know. In this case the goal was to remove the visual style for a list item containing more controls. The child controls will still have its focus style intact.

Comment: You can also just add the `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` in most cases.