# Unwanted dotted-line selection aroudn empty text for WPF RadioButtons

Tags: wpf, radio-button

I have two radio buttons next to each other, and even though each one has no Content/Text, there is this ugly little dotted-line box that shows up next to which ever one has the focus (I think it wrapping the place where text/label would normally be).  Can I get rid of this?

Comment: Try to use search before asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592665/wpf-remove-dotted-border-around-focused-item-in-styled-listbox

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to remove this by simply setting the FocusVisualStyle property to null:

```
<RadioButton FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
```