# Remove list box item dotted border

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have a custom styled `ListBoxItem` with a `Border` surrounding a `ContentPresenter`. (Code found below). My border acts as my selection indicator and turns grey when you select it. All is fine when I use the mouse, but the moment I use my keyboard, an ugly dotted grey border comes out. How do I remove it?

### Pics:

[image: UGLY GREY BORDER]

You can see that when I mouse over/click on the `ListBoxItem`, a border with included background surrounds the item. But an ugly dotted border pops out when I use the keyboard.

### Code:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Border Name="HighlightBorder"  
                            Padding="30"
                            BorderBrush="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            >
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="HighlightBorder" Property="Background" Value="#F3F3F3"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="HighlightBorder" Property="Background" Value="#DFDFDF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="HighlightBorder" Property="Background" Value="#DFDFDF"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: Remove dotted border around focused item in styled listbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592665/wpf-remove-dotted-border-around-focused-item-in-styled-listbox)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592665/wpf-remove-dotted-border-around-focused-item-in-styled-listbox/593541#593541) answer by [jobi-joy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8091/jobi-joy)

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"> 
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/> ....
```