# WPF ListView with GridView not updating SelectionBox after changing SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

### Problem

I have a WPF ListView with a GridView as ListView.View in order to have columns in my ListView. In my code, I am changing the `SelectedIndex` property (bound to an int in my ViewModel) in order to change the selection index. But doing this results in a outline box (see pic) around the previously selected item. Due to visual style I want to remove this outline or move it to the new selected item.

[image: Image showing the unwanted box]

### What I have already tried

I already tried changing the ControlTemplate of the ListViewItem (code below)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <GridViewRowPresenter Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ...}"/>
    </Border.InputBindings>
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#D9EBF9"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCE8FF"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

I also searched for other solutions online, but I wasn't able to find a solution that worked for me.

Comment: Maybe [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593541/2846483).

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks, that was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Thanks @dymanoid

Setting `FocusVisualStyle` to `{x:Null}` in the style of the ListViewItem solved by problem.

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```