# WPF: How does one remove/hide the keyboard focus marquee?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a (hopefully) easy one for you today.

I'm looking to remove the dashed border of a WPF element when it's been selected via keyboard navigation, simply because said marquee is ugly and inconsistent with other styling. I'm only looking to do this on the items of a particular `ListBox`. I'm hoping there is some `SystemColors` key I can set, or some other `Style` property.

Thanks,
   -Logix

[image: a comparison of the element when selected via keyboard or mouse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after plenty more searching. Apparently 'dotted line' was the search term I needed, not 'marquee'.

Anyway, here's the solution (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593541/10412349)):

In the `ListBox` style, set:

```xml
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```